# Passing variables to a POST request from an outside controller

Tags: java, post, get, playframework

Since you guys have been very helpful in my early steps into the Play Framework (thanks for that), here it goes again:

We have a working registration controller, that POSTS all credentials to the database.

But then, we want to make it possible to be immeadiately logged in afterwards. Below is the code that makes this work:

```
    public static void doRegistration(@Valid User user) {

//registering the user

    try{
        SecureController.authenticate(user.username, user.password, false, "MainController.index");
    }catch(Throwable ex){
        MainController.index();
    }
```

This works fine, but it is *not* very safe because it GETs all the credentials to the server. I know I have to edit my **routes** file somehow, but I can't see how.

The routes file:

```
*       /account                                SecureController.login
POST    /account/register                       RegistrationController.doRegistration
GET     /account/register                       SecureController.login
```

Somewhere should be the action SecureController.authenticate, but what do I have to put in the column after the POST... It can't be /account/register, because that fails...

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to do, as you said, is not safe. What you should do (not the only option, only one possibility) is:

- Maintain your current doRegistration action for the user
- Create a service class (that does not inherit Controller). It can be static or require instantiation (with static methods should be enough though).
- Add a @Before method to a common controller that will be executed always. One way is to create a controller with a @Before method and add this controller to all other controllers via the @With annotation, so that @Before will be executed always for all controllers. It requires you to add a @With to each new controller, but I believe it keeps the code quite clean.

The idea would be that the controller calls the authenticate method from the service class.  It's a simple static This method checks the user (if it's enabled, has proper license, whatever) and sets some parameters in the session (via Session object).

To help with this you may want to create another authenticate method in the user that returns the attributes to set (for example in a Map, if it contains an "error" key the user can't be authenticated for some reason). How to do this step can change according to your requirements.

Once the Session has been set, you redirect to the page of your election (main, profile, etc). As you have the common @Before method, this will be executed. This method should verify the credentials in the session (user authenticated, license type, etc) and act accordingly. You have an example in the Secure controller of Play, but you could create your own.

With this, you could user the authenticate method of the service from any controller, allowing authentication via multiple methods, and using a common point to verify the session.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! But I wonder, if I implement the service, then how would I edit the Session, if the service can't extend the Controller (and therefore cannot access the session object)?

I already have the Secure module, but I edited a few things to customize some minor behaviour. So all the logic is already there... Is there any reason to implement the authenticate method in a class that does not extend from Controller? The source from Controller.java is not visible :(

Thanks!

Comment: The Session static (note the Capital S) gives you access to the session without inheriting from Controller... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your issue. The routes file is just a way to configure your URLs to be pretty URLs. If you don't specify them, then it falls back on default {controller}/{method} syntax.

The issue you are having, is that when you call another controller Play performs a redirect to that controller's method, which involves sending a request back to your browser telling it to redirect (this ensures that the state of the application is reflected in the URL within the browser). A redirect needs therefore to send a GET request, and included in the GET request will be your parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I don't want a GET redirect to the controller that authenticates the user. Is there some way to execute the code withing a controller without putting all the parameters in the GET variable?

Comment: The idea of Play is to place all business logic in you model. If your doRegister method wants to perform some specific business logic, then simply call the required methods on your model. If this is not possible, the only other way is to call a non-public static method that is shared by both methods. non-public static methods are not considered Actions in a controller, so simply execute and return control back to the calling method. This way your controllers can share controller logic.

Comment: But if I'm working in another controller, then I need to access the controller from another controller, and that requires a public static method. Unless I would put all the functionality in one Controller, but that can't be the right solution...

Currently I am looking inside the play module [router](http://www.playframework.org/modules/router), would this help?

Thanks!